# Анимация в браузере Microsoft Edge

Tags: html, css, microsoft-edge

У меня есть анимация, и она работает четко во всех браузерах, но когда я открываю страницу через Microsoft Edge, моя анимация не работает, и я не вижу свои изображения. Пока сменяются 2 изображения первое текстовое поле имеет тень `box-shadow`, после переключения на другое изображение второе текстовое поле имеет тень `box-shadow` и т.д со всеми блоками текстов. Что не так с моим кодом?

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

:root {
  --time: 24;
}

.div-txt img,
.div-txt-max img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.div-txt,
.div-txt-max {
  height: 180px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.div-txt p.label,
.div-txt-max p.label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #1F2533;
}

.div-wrap-txt {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  width: 350px;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(1) .div-txt:nth-child(1),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(1) .div-txt:nth-child(2),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(3) .div-txt:nth-child(1),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(3) .div-txt:nth-child(2),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 450px;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /* background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153, 153, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  */
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 8 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 4 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2.66 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 2 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.6 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.33 * 1s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: calc(var(--time) / 1.14 * 1s);
}

.div-txt {
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
  text-align: right;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}

.div-txt-max {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: calc(var(--time) * 1s);
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: block-change;
}

@keyframes block-change {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  12%,
  18% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .widthmax1700 {
    display: block!important;
  }
  .width1700 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .div-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .div-img img {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="widthmax1700" style="display: none;">
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div-wrap-txt">
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Connect</p>
        <p style="color: #414141;">Wear Lia device, turn it on<br>and connect mobile application <br>with the device.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Calibrate</p>
        <p style="color: #414141;">After connection calibrate the way <br> you would like your posture be upright and slouch positions.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-img" style="margin-top: 100px;">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-3">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-4">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-5">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-6">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-7">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="width1700">
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div-wrap-txt">
      <div class="div-txt" style="padding-right: 35px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt" style="padding-right: 35px; margin-top: 50px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div-img">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-3">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-4">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-5">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-6">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-7">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-8">
    </div>
    <div class="div-wrap-txt">
      <div class="div-txt" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px; margin-top: 50px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Я не знаю в чем проблема, в коде или в чем-то другом. Во всех браузерах норм работает все, а в Edge изображений вообще не видно вместо них иконка и блоки не переключаются, т.е не имею тень через каждые 4 секунды. Как это решить? Может сталкивался кто-нибудь, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Да подождите edge скоро перейдёт на хромиум и всё будет путём :-)

Comment: Здравствуйте, @asdas. Понятно тогда, что код вы этот не сами написали. Решение довольно крутое, если бы сами написали, то и отлично бы знали, в чём причина проблемы и как исправить. 

Internet Explorer-11 нужно поддерживать?

Comment: У меня в Firefox картинки не грузятся, похоже хостинг картинок хрень

Comment: Поставьте префиксы для @keyframes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Господа, тут в процессе глубокого анализа выяснилось. ))))))

EDGE - это горе-браузер и не любит `calc()` в анимации.

В первом примере я постарался как мог, доказать, что я прав...

А еще выяснилось, что EDGE не любит `var() переменные` внутри `@keyframes`.

> ***Но тут есть одно большое "НО". Все это может иметь разницу из-за сборки. 
>   Так что прошу коллег проверить ответ в своих браузерах EDGE и дать знать, Будет ли данный пример работать в какой-нибудь сборке. И если есть разница, отредактируйте ответ.***

```css
:root {
  --time: 5;
  --times: 5s;
  --left: 300px;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: grey;
}

div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1
}

@keyframes opacity-1 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes opacity-2 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes opacity-3 {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes left-1 {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(500px - 100px);
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes left-2 {
  from {
    left: 0;
  }
  50% {
    left: var(--left);
  }
  to {
    left: 0;
  }
}

.div-1 {
  animation: opacity-1 5s infinite;
}

.div-2 {
  animation: opacity-2 calc(8 / 2 * 1s) infinite;
}

.div-3 {
  animation: opacity-3 var(--times) infinite;
}

.div-4 {
  animation: left-1 5s infinite;
  position: relative;
}

.div-5 {
  animation: left-2 10s infinite;
  position: relative;
}

.div-6 {
  position: relative;
  left: var(--left);
}

.div-7 {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(500px - 100px)
}
```

```html
<div class="div-1">div-1</div>
<div class="div-2">div-2</div>
<div class="div-3">div-3</div>
<div class="div-4">div-4</div>
<div class="div-5">div-5</div>
<div class="div-6">div-6</div>
<div class="div-7">div-7</div>
```

Решением, для данного ответа, будет смена функции `calc()` на статичные цифры

```css
.div-wrap {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-align: center;
}

.div-txt img,
.div-txt-max img {
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}

.div-txt,
.div-txt-max {
  height: 180px;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.div-txt p.label,
.div-txt-max p.label {
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-family: 'Cabin', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  color: #1F2533;
}

.div-wrap-txt {
  margin-bottom: 70px;
  width: 350px;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(1) .div-txt:nth-child(1),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(1) .div-txt:nth-child(2),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 6s;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(3) .div-txt:nth-child(1),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.div-wrap-txt:nth-child(3) .div-txt:nth-child(2),
.div-txt-max:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 18s;
}

.div-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 600px;
  width: 450px;
  /*  border: 2px solid #ccc;*/
  /* background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(153, 153, 153, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
  */
}

.div-img img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: fade;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 6s);
}

.div-img img:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: 8.3s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: 12s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: 14s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(7) {
  animation-delay: 15s;
}

.div-img img:nth-child(8) {
  animation-delay: 20s;
}

.div-txt {
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: color-change;
  text-align: right;
}

@keyframes color-change {
  0%,
  25%,
  100% {
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  }
  1%,
  24% {
    box-shadow: 0 10px 90px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  }
}

.div-txt-max {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  animation-duration: 24s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-name: block-change;
}

@keyframes block-change {
  0%,
  40%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  12%,
  18% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fade {
  0%,
  20%,
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: auto;
  }
  1%,
  99% {
    z-index: 1;
  }
  8%,
  12% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1170px) {
  .widthmax1700 {
    display: block !important;
  }
  .width1700 {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media all and (min-width: 1170px) {
  .div-wrap {
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }
}

@media all and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .div-img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
  }
  .div-img img {
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="widthmax1700" style="display: none;">
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div-wrap-txt">
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Connect</p>
        <p style="color: #414141;">Wear Lia device, turn it on<br>and connect mobile application <br>with the device.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Calibrate</p>
        <p style="color: #414141;">After connection calibrate the way <br> you would like your posture be upright and slouch positions.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt-max">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div-img" style="margin-top: 100px;">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-3">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-4">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-5">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-6">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-7">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/ff00ff/?text=foto-8">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="width1700">
  <div class="div-wrap">
    <div class="div-wrap-txt">
      <div class="div-txt" style="padding-right: 35px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt" style="padding-right: 35px; margin-top: 50px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="div-img">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-1">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-2">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-3">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-4">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-5">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-6">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-7">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x250/00ddcf/?text=foto-8">
    </div>
    <div class="div-wrap-txt">
      <div class="div-txt" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="div-txt" style="text-align: left; padding-left: 25px; margin-top: 50px;">
        <p class="label">Text</p>
        <p style="color: #6B7684;">Text Text Text, Text Text Text <br> Text Text Text Text <br>Text Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87521/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-air).

Comment: CSS Calc поддерживается в Edge начиная с build 10240+: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/csscalc/

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, у меня сборка `win10 17763`, а `EDGE`  `Microsoft Edge 44.17763.1.0   Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.17763` и ни фига не работает. Винда обновилась два три дня назад, самая последняя сборка

Comment: @Air То, что не работает портянка автора, не значит, что не работает css calc

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, я не примере автора, а о своих испытаниях. Если у тебя мой пример работает, правь ответ и рассказы какая у тебя сборка. Просто интересно уже стало

Comment: Edge 41.16299.820.0 - всё как написано в ответе...

Comment: Внимание! Пользователь своими словами `EDGE - это горе-браузер и не любит calc()` вводит других в заблуждение. Пожалуйста, в работе не руководствуйтесь формулировками: любит, не любит. Есть известный сайт для сверки кроссбраузерности: https://caniuse.com/#feat=calc - как видно на данной странице,`calc()` имеет полную поддержку в Edge. Более того, `calc()` имеет поддержку в более старых Internet Explorer. Это же я могу подтвердить из собственного опыта, много верстаю и постоянно использую calc() в работе, ни в Edge, ни в IE-11 проблем не припоминаю. Также Edge мне кажется нормальным браузером.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, ты свёрнутый сниппет смотрел? `@keyframes left-1 {` использует calc и больше ничего и НЕ работает. Ты пользователям будешь ссылку на caniuse показывать, когда они скажут, что не работает?

Comment: CSS Calc определенно поддерживается Edge. В этом легко убедится, запустив любой пример из документации. Однако, любое ПО имеет баги. В случае Edge баг заключается в том, что calc не работает в сочетании с CSS Animation (https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/105834/) Если столь незначительный баг в редко используемом функционале заставляет вас поливать грязью разработчиков браузера, я и не знаю, что сказать...

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, да ты прав. Не любит (не дружит c... )   `calc()` в анимации, обычном примере  `calc()` работает.  проверял так `left: calc(500px - 100px)` и вот такой пример работает. И я никого не поливаю грязью, всего то назвал идиотами.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, помнишь фильм `Джентельмены удачи`? Цитата - `Здесь помню, а здесь не помню...` Вот и разработчики `EDGE` - `Здесь помню, а здесь не помню...`  Как их назвать...?  Даже, если пример что-то не поддерживается полностью, значит не поддерживается вообще. А теперь, друг мой, представь такую картину. Ты написал сайт сдал его, а эти идиоты, чего-то начудили, и даже в простом, без анимации, правиле CSS `calc()` перестанет работать. И что?

Comment: @Air Такие баги, которые ломают что-то ранее работавщее, они как раз стараются быстро исправлять. MS заботятся об обратной совместимости куда больше, чем о поддержке новых возможностей стандартов. Они скорее не будут править какой-то баг, чтобы не сломать костыли, которые разработчики уже нагородили для его обхода. А в случае с calc + animation, похоже, это не работало в Edge с самого начала.